# ui router doesn't display a template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm started working with ui-router, but nothing shows up in the ui-view. Simplify all to a minimum, I add it to planker and still nothing works. My proj: https://plnkr.co/edit/ERyqonTWZyEhzXd77z0M?p=preview

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<script data-require="angular.js@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script data-require="ui-router@*" data-semver="0.2.15" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-router/805e69bae319e922e4d3265b7ef565058aaff850/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="mainModule.js"></script>
<script src="mainController.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="mainModule">
<h1>This is our views:</h1>
<div ui-view></div>
</body>

</html>
```

mainModule.js:

```
angular.module("mainModule",["ui.router"])
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

    $stateProvider.
        state("adminLogin",{
            url:"/",
            templateURL:"view1.html",
            controller:"coolController"

        }).
        state("adminPanel",{
            url:"/adminPanel",
            templateURL:"view2.html",
            controller:"coolController"
        })

});
```

mainController.js:

```
angular.module("mainModule")
.controller("coolController",['$scope','$state',function($scope, $state) {
    $scope.adminData = {
        login: undefined,
        password: undefined
    }
}])
```

view1.html:

```
<div>YOU DID IT!!</div>
```

view2.html:

```
<h1>It's admin Page!</h1>
```

I hope someone can help solve my problem,because i spend many hours trying to solve the problem but nothing helped =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter for an external template is `templateUrl` not `templateURL`

Comment: thank you a lot Martijn and Jossef, i can't thank you both, because 2 of the decision correct, so first answer will be acceptance

Answer (score 0):

## Use `templateUrl` instead of `templateURL`

You have a typo in your `state` definition. use `templateUrl` instead of `templateURL`

### https://plnkr.co/edit/0OAIoXc8Wa9sWNbt65Is?p=preview

```
angular.module("mainModule",["ui.router"])
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $stateProvider.
            state("adminLogin",{
                url:"/",
                templateUrl:"view1.html",
                controller:"coolController"
              
            }).
            state("adminPanel",{
                url:"/adminPanel",
                templateUrl:"view2.html",
                controller:"coolController"
            })

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    });
```